# Create a table that will automatically drop to a new row after the third column using jinja2 and Flask

Tags: python, flask, jinja2, templating

I have a database filled with Groups that are created by users for posting about topics of their choice. These groups will have subsections that users can go into and post/comment etc. I have made a dashboard that displays the currently available groups and allows users to create their own.

The issue I have is I would like the groups to appear in columns of 3 then drop to a new line and repeat. I currently have it so each result returned takes a full row however this doesn't do much for the web design so I would like it to appear on the next row.

Below is the code I have currently (i is defined in the app.py file):

```
     <div class="row"> 
        {% for group in groups %}
            {% if i == 2 %}
                </div>
                {% set i = 0 %}   
            {% else %} 
                    <div class="col-sm-4">
                        <h2>{{group[0]}}</h2>
                        <p>{{group[1]}}</p>
                    </div> 
                {% set i = i+1 %}
            {% endif %}
        {% endfor %}
    </div>
```

Any help with this would be appreciated.

Comment: if you dont need a real table, but just a 3-cells-in-a-row representation, a css grid can do the trick easily.  which looks to be the case with your css, as you are referring to boostrap grids with `class="row"` rather than true `<tr>`

Comment: something like `#groups {display: grid;grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);grid-gap: : 1em;}` where you get rid of your bootstrap classes and enclose your whole snippet with a `div class="groups">` gets you started.  that means any direct children in that div now obeys css grid rules, fills 3 cells and then repeats next line down.  Try it with some dummy content first.  I used this to replace bootstrap grids on navigation items where I could have too many for one row and wanted to continue on the next.  It's way more powerful than boostrap grids and actually easier once you get it.

Comment: Do you know what you want your HTML/CSS to look like and can't get the jinja2 template to render it? Or are you looking for help determining what your HTML/CSS should be?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Never mind the inline css and other atrocities.  Save this into an html file and open in your browser.

```
<style type="text/css">
    #groups {
        display: grid;
        grid-template-columns: repeat(3, 1fr);
        grid-gap: : 1em;
    }
</style>

<body>
    <div id="groups">
        <div>group1</div>
        <div>group2<div>foo is nested</div>
        </div>
        <div>group3</div>
        <div>group4</div>
    </div>
</body>
```

applied to your template, that's something like:

```
<div id="groups">
    {% for group in groups %}
        <div class="class_to_style_a_group">
            <h2>{{group[0]}}</h2>
            <p>{{group[1]}}</p>
        </div> 
    {% endfor %}
</div>
```